# How to check if the objects' parameter fetches other variable?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have to check the link of browser and if it fetches objects' parameter show me what parameter fetches this var. How to do this? Here is the code:

```js
(function () {
 var windowLink = "",
  str = window.location.pathname.split("/"),
  lastelement = str[str.length - 1],
  pages = {
   page_1 : "index.html", //Put the list of your pages here
   page_2 : "index2.html",
   page_3 : "index3.html",
   page_4 : "index4.html",
   page_5 : "index5.html"
  };
  for(lastelement in pages) {
   windowLink = pages[lastelement];
   console.log(windowLink)
  }
})();
```

Comment: I read this three times and still have no idea what you are asking

Comment: Need to know if "lastelement' equals "page_x" and what exectly "page_x" it equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, you were just overwriting your `lastelement` variable.

```js
(function () {
  var windowLink = "",
      str = window.location.pathname.split("/"),
      lastelement = str[str.length - 1],
      pages = {
        page_1 : "index.html", //Put the list of your pages here
        page_2 : "index2.html",
        page_3 : "index3.html",
        page_4 : "index4.html",
        page_5 : "index5.html",
        page_6 : "js"
      };
  
  console.log("Looking for " + lastelement);

  for(element in pages) {
    windowLink = pages[element];

    if (windowLink === lastelement) {
      console.log("Found at " + element);
      break;
    }
  }
})();
```